# Remove empty paragraphs in reverse and move on to next element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page with text but some of the containers have empty paragraph tags with each one at the end. It's important that I don't remove anything inbetween content, just at the end after the text finishes. My thinking for this would be to loop through the containers first and then check all the paragraph tags in reverse order, remove any that matches a regex and when it hits some content - move on to the next element. I have created a jsfiddle for this but it only removes them from the last panel.

**jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".content").each(function() {
        $($("p").get().reverse()).each(function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            if ($this.html().replace(/\s|&nbsp;/g, '').length == 0) {
                $this.remove();
            } 
            else {
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="content">
    <p>Blah</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>Another Paragraph I want to keep</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
</div>

<div class="content">
    <p>Blah</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>Another Paragraph I want to keep</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
</div>

<div class="content">
    <p>Blah</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>Another Paragraph I want to keep</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>another paragraph</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/659Lejgz/1/

I feel like I am so close but its just out of my reach. Any help would be really great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change `$($("p").get().reverse()).each(function() {`

To: `$($(this).find("p").get().reverse()).each(function() {`

Actually when happens in the original code, is although we're looping through the `.content` elements, in each iteration of the loop, we query the `p` element in the context of the entire documents, and since we reverse the result, we always get the last `p` element of the last `.content` element.

By changing `$("p")` to `$(this).find("p")`, we force jQuery to search for `p` elements only inside the `.content` element we are currently iterating over.

Comment: Thank you for explaining where I was going wrong. I now understand where I was going wrong. Updated my jsfiddle and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues with your code. First you need to specify the paragraphs *relative* to the content div you're looping over, otherwise you're treating them as one set. The other issue is the actual removal needs to cease when you loop backwards and hit the first non-empty paragraph in each div.

This should do the trick:

```js
$(".content").each(function() {
  $($("p", this).get().reverse()).each(function() {
    if ($.trim($(this).text()).length === 0) {
      $(this).remove();
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.content {
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <p>Blah</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>Another Paragraph I want to keep</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
</div>

<div class="content">
  <p>Blah</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>Another Paragraph I want to keep</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
</div>

<div class="content">
  <p>Blah</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>Another Paragraph I want to keep</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>another paragraph</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

add `this` here:-

```
$($("p", this).get().reverse()).each(function() {
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/659Lejgz/2/)

This specifies the context to the current `.content` in the `each`

> jQuery( selector [, context ] )